# Energy in capacitor

Tags: capacitance

When connecting a capacitor to a battery, the battery works to put charges on the capacitor’s plates. First there is no charge on the plates, and battery does 0 work. 
Why, when the battery puts the last charge on the capacitor the work equals V times Q?

I think battery work $\mathrm dq \times(Q-\mathrm dq)/c.$

Answer (score 1):

You may mean

$$W_\mathrm{total}=\int_0^Q { \frac qC  \cdot \mathrm{d}q}=\frac{Q^2}{2C}=\frac{U^2\cdot C}2$$

Answer (score 0):

The power provided to or by a component is always $P=IV$, which is the same as $dE=V \ dQ$. That is a general fact that is always true for any component in any circuit where $I $ is the current through the component and $V $ is the voltage across the component.

For a switched RC circuit, the only important feature of the last bit of charge is that at that point the voltage across the resistor goes to zero and so the voltage across the battery is equal to the voltage across the capacitor. At that point the work done by the battery equals the work done on the capacitor, whereas at previous times the work done by the battery was the sum of the work done on the capacitor and on the resistor.